# How to refresh the data accessed a page in my application, using MVVM Light Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm-light

I have several pages of an application on Windows Phone 7 using MVVM Light, when I log in the application command to call the necessary services and return me to the login page, right there by the data (username and password) to initiate session, and when I come in, in the pages following the data previously bonded user, and do not update the new data, I have the binding properties and raisePropertyChanged. How do I initialize the data again and filled again.

Thank you.

This is a example of my code in ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel:ViewModelBase
{

ILoginService _loginService;
INavigationService _navigationService;

private string _usuario;
public string Usuario
{
  get { return _usuario; }
  set { if (_usuario != value) { _usuario = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Usuario"); } }
}

private string _contraseña;
public string Contraseña
{
  get { return _contraseña; }
  set { if (_contraseña != value) { _contraseña = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Contraseña"); } }
}

public LoginViewModel(ILoginService loginService, INavigationService navigationService)
{
 //my code....
}

}
```

and the code XAML in my View:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Usuario" Style="{StaticResource TextosEtiquetasLogin}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Usuario, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CuadrosTexto}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Contraseña" Style="{StaticResource TextosEtiquetasLogin}"/>
<PasswordBox x:Name="txtPass" Grid.Row="4" Password="{Binding Contraseña, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CuadrosTextoPass}">
```

Thanks, I hope you can help me...

Comment: Have you saved your data anywhere? `IsolatedStorage` or `IsolatedStorageSettings` maybe? Nothing is saved automatically across sessions, you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the SimpleIoc then it treats all resolved classes as singletons by default, including your viewmodels.

What's happening is that when you change users, SimpleIOC isn't resolving new viewmodels for your new user when they go to a page, they're re-using the viewmodel containing the data from the previous user.

You have 2 options:

1)  Resolve the viewmodel so that each time you resolve it you get a new instance of the viewmodel:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

2) When you change user, have the Messenger broadcast a "NewUser" event that is received by your viewmodels so that they can re-load their data based on the new user details:

In LoginViewModel:

```
private void LoginSuccessful()
{
   Messenger.Default.Send<NewUserNotification>(new NewUserNotification("new user name"));
}
```

In other viewmodels:

```
public class MyViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NewUserNotification>(ReceiveAction);
    }

    private void ReceiveAction(NewUserNotification user)
    {
        ReloadMyData(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, choose the first option using, SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());... and with this working correctly... Thanks!!!!